# skillForm.js:25 TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'skills' of 'cache.readQuery(...)' as it is null

Tags: javascript, html, graphql, apollo-server

I am having trouble getting this query to work. The query is passing on the backend but I am getting this error.

```
const SkillForm = () => {
  const [skillForm, setSkillForm] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
  });

  const [addSkill, { error }] = useMutation(ADD_SKILL, {
    update(cache, { data: { addSkill } }) {
      try {
        const { skills } = cache.readQuery({ query: QUERY_SKILLS });

        cache.writeQuery({
          query: QUERY_SKILLS,
          data: { skills: [addSkill, ...skills] },
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }

      // update me object's cache
      const { me } = cache.readQuery({ query: QUERY_ME });
      cache.writeQuery({
        query: QUERY_ME,
        data: { me: { ...me, skills: [...me.skills, addSkill] } },
      });
    },
  });
```

I am trying to add a skill to my query but I am getting the above error...

Comment: `cache.readQuery({ query: QUERY_SKILLS });` returns `null`